# Examples of topological spaces satisfying certain properties

Tags: general-topology

I have learnt that if a regular, second countable space is normal(Theorem 32.1 of Munkres's Topology), and that a regular, second countable space is metrizable(Urysohn metrization theorem, Theorem 34.1). So, I want to analyize these four properties using a Venn diagram, and I would like to know if the diagram is correct, and examples for each part.

[image]

Normality implies regularity, so there is no space that is normal but not regular. Also, metrizable space is always normal. I would like to know some examples each in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 of the diagram. Here are some of my thoughts:

1. $\mathbb{R}_l^2$(Sorgenfrey plane)
2. $\mathbb{R}_l$(Sorgenfrey line)
3. ??
4. A good space, such as $\mathbb{R}$ with Euclidean metric topology
5. ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Sourav's excellent answer. You missed a crucial point in Uryshon Metrization theorem that the space must be Hausdorff.

1.An uncountable discrete space is metrizable given by the discrete metric. It is regular as given any point $x$ and a closed set $C$. we have $\{x\}$ and $C$ are disjoint open neighbourhoods of $\{x\}$ and $C$. Similarly it is normal as given two closed sets $F,C$ they themselves are open disjoint nbds of itself. Also these are $T_{1}$.

It is not second countable as if $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis for $(X,\tau_{\text{discrete}})$ then given an open set $\{x\}$ there exist a basic open set $B$ subset of $\{x\}$ and $x\in B\implies B=\{x\}$ . Thus $\{x\}\in\mathcal{B}\,,\forall\,x\in X$. Thus $\mathcal{B}$ is uncountable.

2 .The cofinite topology on $\Bbb{N}$ is not Hausdorff as given two points $x$ and $y$. Then any open set $U$ containing $x$ is of the form $U=\Bbb{N}\setminus F$ where $F$ is some finite subset of natural numbers. Then any open set containing $y$  say $V=\Bbb{N}\setminus C$ where $C$ is some finite set must have non-empty intersection with $U$. This is because $V\cap U= \Bbb{N}\setminus(F\cup C)$ which is infinite (because $F$ and $C$ were finite).  In fact you could have worked with any infinite set.

Thus it is not metrizable as it is not Hausdorff  .

This set is second countable as the set of all finite subsets of a countable set is countable. Hence you can just take $\{N\setminus F\}_{F\subset\Bbb{N}\,,\text{finite}}$ to be a countable basis.

This is a Normal space as each singleton is closed so it is $T_{1}$ . And given two
disjoint closed sets $F,C$ . You have $F$,$C$ must be finite and hence $\Bbb{N}\setminus F$ and $\Bbb{N}\setminus C$ are disjoint open neighbourhoods. This also proves regularity as each singleton is clsoed.

Comment: Now I see that I was missing a crucial point. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Mr.Gandalf Sauron Excellent explanation.

Answer (score 2):

3. $(X, \tau_{discrete}) $ where $X$ is uncountable.

Then $(X, \tau_{discrete}) $ is metrizable (generated by discere metric ), normal , regular but it is not second countable.

5. $(\Bbb{N}, \tau_{cofinite}) $

Then it is second countable but  not metrizable, regular, normal.

Comment: Indiscrete spaces are regular and normal since there are not many closed sets around.

Comment: @Ruy Hope it looks right now.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a question, why is the cofinite topology in $X$(uncountable) not metrizable?

Comment: @JoshuaWoo a metrizable space must satisfy $T_2$ axiom but cofinite topology on an infinite set is not Hausdorff.

Comment: Ahh I've missed an important point. Thank you